# Is msvcrt a static or dynamic library?

Tags: dll, static-linking, msvcrt

I was reading in MSDN ( [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-library-features?view=vs-2019) ) about the different CRT libraries in Windows.

According to it, `msvcrt.lib` is a:

> Static library for the native CRT startup for use with DLL UCRT and vcruntime.

while `ucrt.lib` is a:

> DLL import library for the UCRT.

This is why `ucrt.lib` have an associated `vcrtbase.dll` dll, but for my understanding of the reference there is no associated dll for `msvcrt`. Yet, I can see there is a `msvcrt.dll` out there, and that its loaded into applications.

So my question is simple, why a static library needs a dll? maybe its because `msvcrt.dll` is actually the same as `msvcrt.lib` but in a dynamic form? If so, why `ucrtbase.dll` is needed? (maybe performance over the outdated `msvcrt`?)

Thanks for any insight that dissolve this mist.

Comment: You may want to specify a Visual Studio version, as these things have changed over time. Also, Visual Studio has long had a `/MT` and `/MD` switch to choose between LIB and DLL versions of the CRT. The existence of a `msvcrt.dll` does not imply that it's the only possibility.

Comment: It has a rather unfortunate name, affected by history.  msvcrt.dll dates from the 1990s and is still around as the dynamic runtime library that Windows executables are linked with.  You can't take a dependency on it, no .lib to link with.  msvcrt.lib today is a static library, just links in the essential startup code that a DLL needs to keep motoring with the dynamic runtime libraries.